# How do I optimize application in android?

Tags: android, optimization, ram

My game extend Views and have struct:

```
onMeasure(){
//load image, sound, font, ect,..
}
onDraw(){
// draw everything
}
oTouchEvent(){
//detect event ..
finish();
System.gc();
}
```

but it using a **very large amount of RAM**, do you have any way to **optimize** the game.

Comment: do you know any good Engine? I'm student and I want learn more about Android. So how to optimize?

Comment: Well for creating a game. The smart and logic thing to do would be to create or use an open source android engine. One of the most popular is http://www.andengine.org/ im actually using it for a game im making now for android. VERY good thanks to @Nicolas Gramlich

Answer (score 0):

In most case you don't have to override View methods like onMeasure, onDraw. Those methods are run on the UI thread and must be blocked by doing input/output, like loading images, fonts, etc.

For 2D graphics you should use Canvas. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html